# BATCH: preventing someone from using CTRL c or CTRL BREAK to bypass my password script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, break

```
@echo off
:home
cd c:/
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (set bit=x64) ELSE (set bit=x86)
title Log in to CMD
color f0
cls
echo.
echo              Cmd Accounts
echo ======================================
echo.
echo [1]  Log In  (access existing Account)
echo.
echo [2]  Register (add an account)
echo.
echo [3]  Delete Account (remove an account)
echo.
echo ============Ethans Security===========
echo.
set RegisterVal=0
set DeleteAcc=0
set /p op=
if %op%==1 goto Login
if %op%==2 goto setReg
if %op%==3 goto setDel
goto home
:setReg
set RegisterVal=1
goto Login
:setDel
set DeleteAcc=1
goto Login
:Login
cls
cd c:/
mkdir enxlogin
cd enxlogin
cls
echo              Cmd Login
echo ======================================
echo.
set /p logName="Enter your username:"
EditV64 -m -p 'Enter your Password:' logPass
EditV32 -m -p 'Enter your Password:' logPass
if exist %logName%.txt goto continue
cls
color fc
echo              Cmd Login
echo ======================================
echo.
echo Acces Denied
pause
goto home
:continue
set /p var= <%logName%.txt
set actPass=%var%
call enx actPass actPass
if %logPass%==%actPass% goto logdone
color fc
cls
echo              Cmd Login
echo ======================================
echo.
echo Acces Denied
pause
goto home
:Register
cd c:/
mkdir enxlogin
cd enxlogin
cls
echo              Cmd Register
echo ======================================
echo.
set /p regName="Enter new username:"
set /p regPass="Enter new password:"
set regName=%regName%
set regPass=%regPass%
call enx regPass regPass
echo %regPass%>%regName%.txt
set regName=NUL
set regPass=NUL
cls
echo             Cmd Register
echo ======================================
echo.
echo Acount Successfully Created
echo.
pause
goto home
:DelAccount
cd c:/
mkdir enxlogin
cd enxlogin
cls
echo            Cmd Delete Account
echo ======================================
echo.
echo Account List
echo ------------
for %%a in ("c:\enxlogin\*") do @echo %%~na
echo.
echo Enter the Account you want to delete:
set /p deletingAcc="Account Name:"
if exist %deletingAcc%.txt goto delaccountnow
cls

echo Account not found
pause
goto DelAccount
echo            Cmd Delete Account
echo ======================================
echo.
:delaccountnow
del %deletingAcc%.txt
cls
echo            Cmd Delete Account
echo ======================================
echo.
echo Successfully Deleted Account
pause
goto home
:logdone
if %RegisterVal%==1 goto Register
if %DeleteAcc%==1 goto DelAccount
set Register=0
set actPass=NUL
set logPass=NUL
cls
echo              Cmd Login
echo ======================================
echo.
echo Successfully logged in!
echo.
pause
color 0f
cd "%userprofile%\Desktop"
cls
exit
```

here's my batch password script it runs on startup of cmd or a batch file but when a user presses ctrl-c or ctrl-break it bypasses the login script

here's what happens I run cmd it starts up all works but when I press CTRL-C it exits and goes back to normal CMD so you can then mess with cmd this is suppost to be protecting people from messing with my cmd in a cool fasion

Comment: the `break` command was supposed to do that, but it doesn't work any more (see `break /?`). But even if it were possible - it wouldn't prevent anyone who knows how to spell "batch" to mess with your bat file.

Comment: ...If your script fully blocks CMD, some would know how to press Win+R and do the same without CMD.

Comment: it still blocks PowerShell as well

Answer (score 4):

The Batch file below can not be cancelled by Ctrl-C, and if it is cancelled by Ctrl-Break the cmd.exe window is closed, so the user never get access to a normal cmd.exe command-line session *via **this** Batch file*.

```
@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1" equ "NonCancelable" goto NonCancelable
start "" /B cmd /C "%~F0" NonCancelable
exit

:NonCancelable
echo You can NOT cancel me!
echo/
set "var="
set /P "var=Enter password (enter Exit to end): "
if /I "%var%" neq "exit" goto :NonCancelable
echo Terminating non cancelable...
pause
exit
```

Comment: when my script is in use CTRL-BREAK still brings you to command line im using the cmd autorun feature to execute my script when cmd starts

Comment: Please, test the above code with _no modification_ in such way.

Comment: You must also specify in the autorun line something like this: `c:\full\path\to\the\BatchFile.bat & exit`

Comment: then when i finish logging in it will not bring me to the console

Comment: it is done this way because if i run a batch file i want it to go back and continue executing the bach file

Comment: your script works but it wont exacly work in mine without major changes

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow you... You just need to insert the first 6 lines of this solution (until `:NonCancelable` label) in your Batch file.

Comment: when i run it. the start command in your code runs but then that start runs my password script and effectivly creates a loop whick breaks everything

Comment: Just add `/D` switch to cmd.exe in the `start` command: `start "" /B cmd /D /C "%~F0" NonCancelable`...

Answer (score 0):

@Aacini above has a good approach, but it's going to prompt you and spit out things you don't need. Here's a more direct solution. I will admit it does not answer OP's request entirely, as this won't stop Ctrl-Break but I was only looking to prevent me from using Ctrl-C in a window with a command running (like a build --watch custom powershell Terminal command).

Given you have originalscript.cmd batch file, instead of invoking directly, invoke via start using the WAIT and B flags. In this way it works almost just like the original script, except Ctrl-C doesn't work. Anyway, here is the invocation you want:

`start "" \WAIT \B originalscript.cmd param1 param2 etc`

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue.

When terminating a batch script by ctrl+C a cmd session starts at the %CD% direcory of the bathscript. I solved this issue by lanching a batch script trough another batch script as shown below:

```
::launcher
@ECHO off
CD "directory of the batch script"
batchscript.cmd
EXIT
```

when batchscript.cmd is terminated by ctrl+C it returns to the launcher which immediatelly closes because of the EXIT statement

(The CD statement is needed when running as administrator. This is because the CD variable of the batch script will then be equal to C:\Windows\System32. However, the CD statement can be omitted if the batch scripts' directory is included in the PATH variable)

Comment: For me it closes out of both of them.